# Hibernate Postgres could not deserialize

Tags: hibernate, postgresql

```
public List<Marki> getMarki()
      {
        List<Marki> markiList = null;
        try {
            Session session = HibernateSession.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
            session.beginTransaction();
            Query q = session.createQuery("from Marki ");
            if ( q != null ) {
                markiList = ( List<Marki> ) q.list();
            }
            // session.getTransaction().commit();
        } catch ( Exception e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return markiList;
 }
```

Mapping

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="bazaMap.Marki" table="marki" schema="public">
        <id name="id" type="int">
            <column name="id" />
            <generator class="assigned" />
        </id>
        <property name="marka" type="serializable">
            <column name="marka" unique="true" />
        </property>
        <set name="modeles" inverse="true">
            <key>
                <column name="markaid" not-null="true" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="bazaMap.Modele" />
        </set>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>


N



CREATE TABLE marki
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  marka character varying(32)[],
  CONSTRAINT glowny PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT marki_marka_key UNIQUE (marka)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE marki
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

> FO: Hibernate: select marki0_.id as id3_, marki0_.marka as marka3_
>   from public.marki marki0_
>               INFO: could not read column value from result set: marka3_; could not deserialize
>               SEVERE: org.hibernate.type.SerializationException: could not deserialize
>                 at org.hibernate.util.SerializationHelper.deserialize(SerializationHelper.java:217)
>                 at org.hibernate.util.SerializationHelper.deserialize(SerializationHelper.java:240)
>                 at org.hibernate.type.SerializableType.fromBytes(SerializableType.java:82)
>                 at org.hibernate.type.SerializableType.get(SerializableType.java:39)
>                 at org.hibernate.type.NullableType.nullSafeGet(NullableType.java:163)
>                 at org.hibernate.type.NullableType.nullSafeGet(NullableType.java:154)
>                 at org.hibernate.type.AbstractType.hydrate(AbstractType.java:81)
>                 at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.hydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2096)
>                 at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadFromResultSet(Loader.java:1380)
>                 at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.instanceNotYetLoaded(Loader.java:1308)
>                 at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRow(Loader.java:1206)
>                 at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:580)
>                 at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:701)
>                 at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:236)
>                 at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2220)
>                 at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2104)
>                 at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2099)
>                 at org.hibernate.hql.classic.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:912)
>                 at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:172)
>                 at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1121)
>                 at org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:79)
>                 at DataFetcher.getMarki(DataFetcher.java:40)

1.All the Mappings code were generated by NetBeans. Any ideas what could be wrong or even better - how to fix it?

blah
"Your post does not have much context to explain the code sections; please explain your scenario more clearly."

Comment: stackoverflow is smart. you really should "explain your scenario more clearly" like it suggested. You should add more information on what the problem is, like an exact error message or stack trace.

Comment: I did add the error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bet this is your problem:

```
marka character varying(32)[],
```

You probably don't want an *array* of characters. This is probably what you intend:

```
marka varchar(32),
```

Last I checked Hibernate doesn't know how to deal with Postgres arrays out of the box, because few RDBMSes support them.

Comment: How do I define varchar(32) in Postgres?

Comment: `varchar(32)` is shorthand for `character varying(32)` and both will "just work."